# switching Google Analytics to new domain name

Tags: google-analytics

We switched our site to a new domain name, old one redirects to the new one.
E.g., we had siteA.com, switched to a new domain name siteB.com (it's still the same backend,etc, just a new domain).

I want to keep receiving analytics data from siteB.com on the current GA account - I want to see the stats for previous(siteA) and current (siteB) domains on the same chart

What changes do I need to do in GoogleAnalytics to get this working?

Comment: Hi, this question isn't related to specific code that you're having problems with, so it's off topic. You might want to try posting to Webmasters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a default installation of GA (without an explicitly set cookie domain or cross-domain tracking etc.) you do not need to make any changes to the tracking code. GA will happily track every website where the GA code is located regardless of the domain name.

Only if you have supplied a domain name in the tracking code, e.g. in the configuration for the linker plugin if you do cross-domain tracking, or to set a cookie domain to a value other than "auto" you need to swap it for your new domain name. This is not part of the standard configuration however.

The domain name setting in the property and view settings provides a base url for in page analysis and page preview, it does not affect tracking in any way.

You should add your new domain name to the referral exclusion list in the property settings to avoid self-referrals.